# Loading Image bitmap from user picked image into imageview doesn't set image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory, startactivityforresult

A **beginner** here..

I'm setting a image into Image View that will be picked by user, But when I'm picking image the imageview doesn't get the image loaded.

M app is just opening the file chooser, I'm choosing the image and its just **not loading the picked image in imageview.**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
     />
```

in **java**..

```
ImageView logoimage=findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);
```

**I have this onclick listener on my Imageview..**

```
logoImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent fileChoosingIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                fileChoosingIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(fileChoosingIntent,10);
            }
        });
```

**OnActivityResults method**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(resultCode==10){

            logoImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData().getPath()));
        }
    }
```

> androdi studio is giving this warning "Method invocation 'getData' may
>   produce 'NullPointerException'" on data.getData() method...

I also have tried glide

```
Glide.with(this).load(data.getData()).into(logoImage);
```

I'm getting same results, blank imageview.

Rest of code is confidential( Can't a beginner have secret code..? :p)

**NOTE- Its not showing anything in logcat**
Thank you so much for your suppport... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistaken the codes in the `onActivityResult` method. The `requestCode` is the one that identifies your request.

From the `Activity` source code:

> **requestCode** The integer request code originally supplied to `startActivityForResult()`, allowing you to identify who this result came from.
>
> **resultCode** The integer result code returned by the child activity through its `setResult()`.

You should use `resultCode` to make sure that your request was successful though.

When it comes to the `NullPointerException` warning, you should always check if used nullable variable isn't in fact `null` before accessing its fields or methods.

So your `startActivityResult()` method using Glide should look more like this:

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 10) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
               Glide.with(this).load(data.getData()).into(logoImage);
            } else {
              // optional null data handling
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: wooooooooooooohhhooooooooooooo it worked...

but what is "resultCode == RESULT_OK"

we only added a if condition to check resultCode == RESULT_OK and then it worked? but without using this why did not my code work though the IF statement's body is same ... we only added a condition ..how?

thanks

Edit- and how the value was being null? we just added a if condition and the value is not null now..is this magic?

Comment: @Monk: No, changing the statement `resultCode == 10` to `requestCode == 10` is what made the code work. As I wrote previously, you checked the wrong code against the code you used to start your request.  The `resultCode == RESULT_OK` is just kind of a safety net to make sure you are processing a successful response.

Comment: hey but I dont check this then logically my all statements should run , as I dont have any "If statement" ..m I wrong ??
:-(

Comment: @Monk: The `data` value wasn't `null`, it _could_ be `null`. If it was `null`, the code inside the if-statement woudn't execute. You should always check whether nullable variables aren't null before using them to avoid `NullPointerException` which will crash your app.

Comment: @Monk: If I understood you correctly, yes, if you didn't check anything, the code would still work in most of the cases. The problem starts when you are making multiple different request or any of this request fails.

Comment: @Monk: Let me explain the ifs:
`if (requestCode == 10)` filters responses by requests they corresponds to. Without that you can't be sure if you are processing a proper response.
`if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)` checks if the request finished successful. You can use that to avoid running unnecessary piece of code, because in most of cases you want to process successful requests, not the failed ones.
`if (data != null)` checks if you can safely access `data` fields and methods. If you try to access any member of the null object, you will end up with `NullPointerException` and a crashed app.

Comment: @Monk: For further information please check Android Developer Guide on [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Answer (score 0):

```
logoImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData().getPath()));
```

You are not getting a file, so `decodeFile()` is not going to work.

The best solution, by far, is to add [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to your project, then give the `Uri` (`data.getData()`) to the library to load into your `ImageView`. To be blunt: anyone who *doesn't* do this needs a very good justification.

The most direct equivalent of your current code is to use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Then, use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to populate the `ImageView`. This will do that work on the main application thread (irritating peer developers/managers) and freezing your UI (irritating users). That's why you should just use Glide or Picasso, as they handle the background threading for you, along with lots of other things (e.g., caching).

Comment: androdi studio is giving this warning "Method invocation 'getData' may produce 'NullPointerException'" on data.getData() method...


I also have tried glide 
Glide.with(this).load(data.getData()).into(logoImage);

I'm getting same results, blank imageview.

thank you...

Comment: @Monk: Check Logcat to see if there are messages from Glide, and review [their debugging docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html). The warning is simply pointing out that, in theory, `data` might be `null`. You should check to see if `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK` and whether `data` is `null` before trying to use `data`.

Comment: Hi...it worked but how just adding a one more If condition solve an error? we had the same code under "If statement" but that time it did not work why??